# Changing the name of a generated data model property in swagger-codegen

Tags: c#, swagger-codegen, handlebars.net

I am generating a data model using swagger-codegen. The template

```
/// <summary>
/// {{^description}}Gets or Sets {{{name}}}{{/description}}{{#description}}{{description}}{{/description}}
/// </summary>{{#description}}
/// <value>{{description}}</value>{{/description}}
[JsonProperty("{{baseName}}")]
public {{{datatype}}} {{name}} { get; {{#isReadOnly}}private {{/isReadOnly}}set; }
```

generates

```
/// <summary>
/// Description of property.
/// </summary>
/// <value>Description of property.</value>
[JsonProperty("property_name")]
public String property_name { get; set; }
```

How can I change the case of the `property name` from snake_case to PascalCase? I imagine I have to do some kind of transformation to `{{name}}` but I'm not very familiar with handlebars templates.

```
/// <summary>
/// Description of property.
/// </summary>
/// <value>Description of property.</value>
[JsonProperty("property_name")]
public String PropertyName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you using an old version of Swagger Codegen? The recent versions should have convert the C# property name into PascalCase automatically.

Comment: You're right - this works with the CSharp generator! I'm trrying to create a generator for .NET Standard so I'm starting fresh. I didn't see the C# generator has this. Thanks!

Comment: There's also a C# 2.0 generator, which is used mainly by Unity developers. If you want to build a new generator, I would suggest you to start a discussion via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/new as someone else may have started working on one already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything built into Swagger Codegen, but with handlebars.net, you can [register a helper](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net#registering-helpers) to convert the string to PascalCase:

```
Handlebars.RegisterHelper("PascalCase", (writer, context, parameters) => {
  // paramaters[0] should be name, convert it to PascalCase here
});
```

My c# is dusty enough that I don't remember if there is a builtin way of PascalCasing a string, but it shouldn't be too hard to do if there isn't.

Then call it from your template:

```
public {{{datatype}}} {{PascalCase name}} ...
```

Edit:  It looks like [Swagger Codegen uses jmustache](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#modifying-the-client-library-format) under the hood, and from a quick glance, but I think you can do [something similar with Lambdas](https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache#lambdas)